# Proving equivalence relation for 7 | (3a + 4b)

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, relation-algebra

I know this might be quite trivial, but I just can't seem to figure out how to prove $$R = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} : 3a + 4b \text{ is divisible by } 7\}$$ is a symmetric relation, i.e., if $aRb$, then $bRa$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers

Comment: Hint: $3a+4b$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $3a-3b=3a+4b-7b$ is divisible by $7$.

Comment: Well, what's the definition of equivalence relation.  Reflexive:  Is a R a for all a in Z.  That is is (a, a) in R.  That is, is 3a + 4b divisible by 7.  If so R is reflexive.  Is R symetric?  If 7 divides 3a + 4b does it follow that 7 divides 4a + 3b?  If 7 divides 3a + 4b and 7 divides 3b + 4 c does it follow that 7 divides 3a + 4c?  If so, you've proven it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$(3a+4b)+(4a+3b)=7(a+b)$.

Comment: Thanks. The hint was spot-on.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $3a+4b=7c\implies3b+4a=7(a+b-c)$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Assume $aRb$. Then $7 \mid (3a+4b)$. What can you say about $7\mid(4a+3b)$ instead?